# Is there a way to calculate the average queue time of an entire column that contains data in time format

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have imported a data extracted from a cisco call center in SQLITE table. These data deals with information related to the  incoming calls .

Among this table , there is a column called "queue time"  which indicates the time spent by the caller waiting in the queue before reaching an agent  . I would like to write a select query that calcultes the average time of the "queuetime" and the result should be in time format .
I tried with many queries but without any success:

```
SELECT strftime('%H:%M:%S',AVG("QUEUETIME")) 
FROM "CSQ Agent Report"
```

The result is the following:

```
[('12:00:00',), ('12:00:00',), ('12:00:00',), ('12:00:00',), ('12:00:00',), ('12:00:00',)]
```

For:

```
SELECT  AVG("QUEUETIME"))) FROM "CSQ Agent Report"
```

The result is the folowing:

```
[(0.0,)]
```

Here is a partial copy of the Queuetime column :

```
00:00:05
00:00:05
00:00:08
00:00:03
00:00:02
00:01:45
00:00:05
00:00:03
00:00:06
00:00:24
00:00:06
00:00:46
```

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must convert the time values to numbers which are unix timestamps since the start of epoch which is `'1970-01-01 00:00:00'` to perform the average calculation and after you get the numeric result you must convert back to time with the function `time()`:

```
SELECT TIME(AVG(strftime('%s', Queuetime)), 'unixepoch') avg_time
FROM CSQAgentReport
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=95f9f720c92a9436140cf170d92851f6).
Results:

```
> | avg_time |
> | :------- |
> | 00:00:18 |
```